# Get index of element in a struct c++

Tags: c++, indexing, struct, element

I want to get the index of an element in a struct.Below is the code. However it is only returning 0 as the output. Assuming I have added data to the struct below, the function find_index does not return the index of the element.It only returns 0;

```
struct Person{
    string name;
    int age;
    float spread_prob;
    float disease_prob;
    float recover_prob;
    status disease_status;
    int sick_day;
};

Person person[9];

int find_index(string m){
    for(i=0;i<9;i++){
        if(m==person[i].name){
            return i;   
        }   
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Where/how is `person` defined? What are you calling it with? Please expand your question to make it a [mcve]

Comment: Tons of errors in your code, including `i` not being defined, scope of function not being clarified (if it is in main consider using a lambda to access the struct) and unnecessary use of statements like return 0.

Comment: @Anirban166 this is just a snippet of my code, I have already defined i in my code. The function is not in the main.

Comment: Are you sure that the value of m exactly equals someone in the array? Indeed std::string::operator== compares value strictly, e.g. "Aileen" does **NOT** equal "Aileen\0", even though you would see they are same in output.

Comment: Don't edit question in a way which invalidate existing answer. better to ask another question then. (and be more careful if it was a typo).

Comment: returning 0 as not found value seems strange as it is a valid index, so you don't know if value is not found, or if first element is the right one.

Comment: Are you  sure your data have been added proper? For example, if `m = "Tom\n"` while `person`s only contain a person called "Tom". ( This case happens when you use getline, which won't leave out `'\n'`

Comment: @Ter How would I get rid of the '\n'

Answer (score 1):

The `return 0` is inside your for-loop. So when the first iteration match, `return i` is return `0` and if this is not the case `return 0` is called. Move the `return 0` out of your loop, so the loop will not break after one iteration.

Comment: So I had it outside the for loop and it was still returning 0;

Comment: I don't know your used example names, to help you more. It would be helpful, if you also post how you fill the `person`-variable and what is `m` in your example. You could also add a print-output inside of your if-condition to check out, whats the values for `m` and `person[i].name`.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, your code has syntactical errors such as the loop variable `i` being not defined and logical errors such as returning 0 inside the for-loop, (which means that irrespective of any index match, your function will only return 0) and returning 0 itself is an error since that implies your string or name is found at the first index. If your not following array indices, consider adding a `+1` to the return statement. Otherwise, use something else, such as a `-1` or any negative number to indicate that the string is not found/matched in any index.

Next, your code is not defined under proper scope for a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) (one which can be directly copy-pasted and tested on our compilers).

Considering the `Person` objects are in `main()`, I have created a lambda / temporary-function inside the main scope which should help you solve your problem: (considering struct's `name` member and an array of 3 `Person` objects for demonstration)

```cpp
#include <iostream>

struct Person
{
    std::string name;
};

int main()
{
  Person person[3]; 
  person[0].name = "Karl"; 
  person[1].name = "John";
  person[2].name = "Felix";

  auto findIndex = [=](std::string m)
  { for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++) 
    { if(m == person[i].name)
      return i;
    }
    return -1;    
  };

  std::cout << findIndex("Felix");
  std::cout << "\n";
  std::cout << findIndex("Blaze"); 
}
```

Output :

```
2
-1
```

Comment: thanks,the function I  created is in a class and it is used in the main.If this works in the class I will update you

Answer (score 0):

```
int find_index(string m){
    int ret = -1; // -1 denotes not available

    for(i=0;i<9;i++){
        if(m==person[i].name){
            ret = i;
            break;   
        }   
    }
    return ret ; //If it matches it will return the index on which it breaks.
}
```

You can use a return variable.